# jQuery used inside Angular

Tags: angularjs

I know this is a subject discussed too many times. I know that jQuery may create problems. I know most sites advise try to avoid the use of jQuery, however my question is:
***How may I manipulate the DOM inside an Angular directive if not using jQuery?*** Even in Angular docs there is intensive use of jQuery lite inside directives. I 'd appreciate your opinions in that.

Comment: use the second parameter of link function

Answer (score 0):

In link function you can actually manipulate DOM.

```
app.directive('sampleDirective', function() {
    return {
        ...
        link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
            //here actually you can manipulate DOM using ele.
        }
    }
})
```

Angular has bilt-in jqLite(subset of jQuery). Find it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

> Note: Do DOM manipulations only in directive.